# Re-Populating Session values with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a form that uses jquery to show/hide if an item from a `DDL` is selected and displays another text field for the user to fill in.

I now am using session to store all the values from the form as it is over multiple pages. When the user clicks the previous page button I am `Repopulating()` with the session values.

So some of the textboxes were in `Panels` and I would have to check `if` the `radio button` was `checked` which hid the `panel` and make the `panel.Visible` if checked then populatlate the value from session.

How can I do this with jQuery in the code behind? Or should I just uses Panels?

This is what I am doing when the Page loads.

```
$(function () {

 $('#whereIncident').hide();

 var result = $('.drpIncidentTookPlace').val();

 if (result == "Victim-Other") {
    $('#whereIncident').show(400);
 } else {
    $('#whereIncident').hide(300);
 }
});
```

I am saving my session against a class. And repopulating depending what was chosen.

```
 SessionVars.Current.Incident.incidentPlace = drp_IncidentTookPlace.SelectedValue;
 SessionVars.Current.Incident.incidentPlaceOther = txt_other_type.Text;
```

Repop()

```
 drp_IncidentTookPlace.SelectedValue = SessionVars.Current.Incident.incidentPlace;
      if (drp_IncidentTookPlace.SelectedValue == "Victim-Other")
       {
           txt_other_type.Text = SessionVars.Current.Incident.incidentPlaceOther;
       }
```

How would I use jQuery to re-show the hidden `other` field when rePopulating my session? as this is in the code behind?

Comment: This is a very bad title. Please update it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: What is `SessionVars`?

Comment: It looks like the only question here is how to call a client script from the server side. If so, here is your answer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11098/Use-Call-RegisterStartUpScript-RegisterClientScrip

Comment: `Sessionvars` is a method that has my incident `class` in.        SessionVars session=(SessionVars)HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"];
                if (session == null)
                {
                    session = new SessionVars();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"] = session;
                }
                return session; So I can add more classes to the session and keep track of multiple objects.